# Pass value from single across completable to result in rxjava Android

Tags: android, rx-java2

**This is what I want:**

> 1. Check if I have data about products in database.
> 2. If I have data I run Single to get data from DB.
> 3. If not I run Single for get data from backend
> 4. If I get response I want to save data in DB using Completable.
> 5. After saving data I want to map values from step 2 or 3 to view model
> 6. In result I want to send data to activity.

This is what I have now:

```
checkProductsInDBUseCase.run()
                .flatMap {
                    if (it) {
                        getProductsFromDBUseCase.run()
                    } else {
                        getProductsUseCase.run(3)
                    }
                }.map {
                    it.products.map { item -> item.toViewModel() }
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeBy(
                        onSuccess = {
                            view.showBikes(it)
                        },
                        onError = {
                            view.showBikesError(it.message.toString())
                        }
                ).addTo(disposables)
```

Between flat map and map I need to run `saveDataUseCase(it)`, but I don't know how to pass `it`from completable to map. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your saveDataUseCase() is Completable then you can do this

```
checkProductsInDBUseCase.run()
        .flatMap {
            if (it) {
                getProductsFromDBUseCase.run()
            } else {
                getProductsUseCase.run(3)
            }
        }
        .faltMap {
             saveDataUseCase(it).toSingleDefault(it)
        }
        .map {
            it.products.map { item -> item.toViewModel() }
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeBy(
                onSuccess = {
                    view.showBikes(it)
                },
                onError = {
                    view.showBikesError(it.message.toString())
                }
        ).addTo(disposables)
```

But if you change return type of saveDataUseCase() to Unit, you can use [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344487/fred)'s answer. It would be better

Answer (score 0):

Here I'd use `doOnSuccess`. This seems ideal especially because you're creating a side effect, which we usually use the `doOnXXX` methods for.

```
checkProductsInDBUseCase.run()
            .flatMap {
                if (it) {
                    getProductsFromDBUseCase.run()
                } else {
                    getProductsUseCase.run(3)
                }
            }
            .doOnSuccess {
                 saveDataUseCase(it)
            }
            .map {
                it.products.map { item -> item.toViewModel() }
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy(
                    onSuccess = {
                        view.showBikes(it)
                    },
                    onError = {
                        view.showBikesError(it.message.toString())
                    }
            ).addTo(disposables)
```

The method will not change the result of the `flatMap` so you will still get the correct object inside the `map` function.